# What is the correct implementation of addToLeftPlayerPos

Tags: haskell, monads, frp, reader, writer

I'm trying to follow [this paper](https://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/36159/1/paper.pdf) on functional reactive programming but I'm stuck on the second example in section 4.2.

I got the first example with the reader transformer up and running:

```
module Main where

import FRP.BearRiver    
import Control.Monad.Trans.MSF.Reader

type Game = Ball
type Ball = Int

type GameEnv = ReaderT GameSettings

data GameSettings
    = GameSettings
      { leftPlayerPos  :: Int
      , rightPlayerPos :: Int
      }

ballToRight :: Monad m => MSF (GameEnv m) () Ball
ballToRight =
    count >>> arrM addToLeftPlayerPos
    where
      addToLeftPlayerPos =
          (\n -> (n +) <$> asks leftPlayerPos)

hitRight :: Monad m => MSF (GameEnv m) Ball Bool
hitRight = arrM (\i -> (i >=) <$> asks rightPlayerPos)
```

But with the next step I'm struggling. I can't figure out how to introduce a writer transformer correctly, as I don't get it even to compile:

```
module Main where

import FRP.BearRiver
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.MSF.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.MSF.Writer

type Game = Ball
type Ball = Int

type GameEnv m =
    WriterT [String] (ReaderT GameSettings m)

data GameSettings
    = GameSettings
      { leftPlayerPos  :: Int
      , rightPlayerPos :: Int
      }

ballToRight :: Monad m => MSF (GameEnv m) () Ball
ballToRight =
    count >>> arrM addLeftPlayerPos >>> arrM checkHitR
    where
      addLeftPlayerPos =
          (\n -> (n +) <$> asks leftPlayerPos)
      checkHitR n = do
          rp <- asks rightPlayerPos
when (rp > n) $ tell ["Ball is at " ++ (show n)]
```

Actually the line with the function call `addLeftPlayerPos` is the problematic one, as the function `arrM addLeftPlayerPos` isn't given in the paper and my version seems to lack the `WriterT` type signature as the type alias `type GameEnv m ...` suggests

What could be the correct implementation of the `addLeftPlayerPos` function?

Edit:
The compiler error is:

```
 Expected type: MSF (GameEnv m) () Ball
    Actual type: MSF (ReaderT GameSettings m1) () () 
• In the expression: 
    count >>> arrM addToLeftPlayerPos >>> arrM checkHitR
```

Comment: Could you provide your attempted implementation and the error?

Comment: Sure, my implementation is just the one in the where clause an the error message I added to the post.

Comment: also I added the relevant parts into [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/frosch03/bc0e3f50aa4919d65bf4d410d0d9f152/474f139a98e42a8bc3e689407642b2d52e546905)

Comment: Have you tried to `lift (asks leftPlayerPos)`?  I haven't tested, but that is the normal way you use a monad underneath a transformer.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't help alot: 
     `• Couldn't match type ‘ReaderT GameSettings m2’ ` with `‘WriterT [String] (ReaderT GameSettings m)’` ... that is: `Expected type: MSF (GameEnv m) () Ball` instead of `Actual type: MSF (ReaderT GameSettings m2) () ()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Some phrasing

When you have a transformer stack you must "lift" your operations to run the inner-monad functions.  for example:

```
type MyMonad a = Transformer1 (Transformer2 IO) a
```

The stack here is Transformer1 of Transformer2 of IO.  The "outer" monad is Transformer1 which wraps Transformer2 with an inner-most (or base, bottom) monad of IO.  In your case the stack is actuall a Writer of a Reader of some unknown monad `m`, all good.

Now if we want to run `f :: Transformer2 IO a` from within a function `g :: MyMonad` we must `lift f`.  Similarly, if we have `getLine :: IO String` and we wish to run that from within `g :: Transformer1 (Transformer2 IO) a` then we can `lift (lift getLine)`.

## Lifting

If you import `Control.Monad.Trans.Class` you can lift your ReaderT operations.  For example `lift (asks ...)` instead of just `asks ...`.

This *does* help a lot.  The error you commented probably is due to the use of `asks` in `checkHitR`.

## One More Type Error

After doing our lifting we have the error:

```
frosch.hs:23:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: MSF (GameEnv m) () Ball
        Actual type: MSF
                       (WriterT [[Char]] (ReaderT GameSettings m)) () ()
```

This is because your `checkHitR` doesn't return the value `rp` (which I assume it should).  Fixing that issue gives us our final code of:

```
module Main where

import FRP.BearRiver
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.MSF.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.MSF.Writer

type Game = Ball
type Ball = Int

type GameEnv m =
    WriterT [String] (ReaderT GameSettings m)

data GameSettings
    = GameSettings
      { leftPlayerPos  :: Int
      , rightPlayerPos :: Int
      }

ballToRight :: Monad m => MSF (GameEnv m) () Ball
ballToRight =
    count >>> arrM addLeftPlayerPos >>> arrM checkHitR
    where
      addLeftPlayerPos =
          (\n -> (n +) <$> lift (asks leftPlayerPos))
      checkHitR n = do
          rp <- lift (asks rightPlayerPos)
          when (rp > n) $ tell ["Ball is at " ++ (show n)]
          pure rp
```